# How can I replace piano hinge

Tags: furniture, hinges

I have an old shelf with doors supported on piano (klavir) hinges, which are rusty and crooked. Most of the screws on the hinge are barely holding on, so for now I am ruling out the option to replace or repair the hinge.

I already have a hinge hole cutter, which was last used some years ago with reasonable success. It looks to me that plugging a pair of "normal" (Euro) hinges would be great if possible.

My question: is it possible, and if so what should I be watchful for?

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: Not at the moment, but definitely I should.

Comment: Second the picture request - at the moment your question is rather vague.  Without something specific to look at it's hard to answer meaningfully.